# rpm -V does not detect all the missing files of a package

Tags: yum, rpm

I am running CentOS 7. I removed all files of emacs utility under folder `/usr/libexec/emacs/24.3/`
When I issue command: `rpm -V` it returns nothing, like no files from the package are missing. Even when I run `yum reinstall emacs`, the files that I removed are not back.

Shouldn't `rpm -V` check for all the missing files of a package. Why are these files I removed not detected as missing. Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `emacs` packaged for CentOS, I do not see that the path `/usr/libexec/emacs/24.3/` belongs to it, so trying to verify the `emacs` package will not show changes in that directory.

The path `/usr/libexec/emacs/24.3/` looks to belong to the `emacs-common` package (`rpm -qf /usr/libexec/emacs/24.3/`).  If you were to run your same test, but verify the `emacs-common` package (`rpm -V emacs-common`), you should see the missing files.

Comment: That is a sharp guess. Thank you, you helped me figure it out. Command `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/libexec/emacs/24.3` returns `emacs-common`.